# How data stored in redis service in docker container

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, docker-container, redis-cli

Here is a docker container with redis service:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redisdata:/data
```

I enter the container and call redis-cli `ping` command with the answer `PONG`:

```
docker-compose exec redish bash
.../data# redis-cli ping
```

Is it possible to find out how and what kind of data is stored in the redis database?

Answer (score 3):

If this helps,

From the command line, you can use

```
redis-cli --scan
```

or

```
redis-cli KEYS '*'
```

But these again just give you the keys that are stored in the server. Alternatively if you can access it using a GUI client use the [redis-desktop-manager](https://redisdesktop.com/) then you can inspect the container using

```
docker inspect <containerId>
```

and get the IP part and put it in the desktop manager.

It gives a nice UI with all the keys and values.